# How to show set locations in a google map and add navigate button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am looking to create a map application.  I want it to show a location that user selects from a list and show here the location is, then add a button on the map so that the user can navigate from there current location to the one selected.

I have looked at tutorials but cannot find anything that does this.

Anyone know where I might find a tutorial that shows this or how I can extend my simple map to show a given location.

```
import com.ff.org.R;
```

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Locbrad extends MapActivity {

```
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map1);

      MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote up a [simple tutorial](http://joshclemm.com/writing/android-tabs-with-interacting-map-and-list-views/) that shows a ListView and MapView in two tabs (and one activity).  In the tutorial, when you click a location in the ListView, the MapView zooms to that location.

It might be a good start for your application.  It doesn't have a button on the map to go to the next list item, but since both the MapView and ListView are in the same activity, you have a reference to the list, and you can zoom to the next item.

Comment: I want to navigate from the user current location to one they have selected but thanks i'll check it out